# Canonical equals() method for Java as on Android Developers site

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, equals

[Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Object.html)'s how the site suggests you to write an `equals()` method.

```
   @Override 
   public boolean equals(Object o) {
     if (this == o) {
       return true;
     }

     if (!(o instanceof MyType)) {
       return false;
     }

     MyType lhs = (MyType) o;

     return primitiveField == lhs.primitiveField &&
             referenceField.equals(lhs.referenceField) &&
             (nullableField == null ? lhs.nullableField == null
                                    : nullableField.equals(lhs.nullableField));
   }
```

Now, I am surely misunderstanding something, but suppose you have two MyType objects m1 and m2, and e.g. if `m1.referenceField` is `null`, this is not going to work, because when it reaches

```
referenceField.equals(lhs.referenceField)
```

it will throw a NullPointerException. Where could be my logic error?

Comment: Check for null, then.  Why so hard?  The real question is: why does your object have null references for private members?

Comment: That would be the point of the `nullableField`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the point is that this would be a type where `referenceField` was guaranteed to be non-null, e.g. it's checked in the constructor.

Compare this with `nullableField`, where the nullity is checked as part of `equals`.